# Clean urls cannot get function id in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using CodeIgniter in my project and I need to clean the url. I use this htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $0 !^(index\.php|images|captcha|css|js|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [L]
```

The url redirect is working fine.
If I use `localhost/example/controll/` this works fine, if I have an `controll` as controller, but if I need to pass a value to the controller like `localhost/example/controll/how-to-design/` it says 404 not found. Do I need to get the how-to design in `controll` class and process it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the URL `localhost/example/controll/how-to-design` translates to a controller called `controll` and a method called `how-to-design`

CI will be looking for a method called `how-to-design`, which presumably doesn't exist.

If you want to pass that parameter to `controll` the URL needs to be:

`controll/index/how-to-design`

```
function index($param)
{ 
   echo $param; // echoes how-to-design
}
```

you can probably fix this with [routing](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html) or by using `index` in your URI.

Comment: Use `function index($param = FALSE)`, because if no parameter is given it will output error. You could also use `$param = $this->uri->segment(3);` where 3 is the segment.

Answer (score 0):

You can't by default in CodeIgniter pass parameters to the controller index function - in your example CI would be looking for a method called 'how-to-design' (which in itself is impossible, as dashes are not permitted in PHP function naming conventions).

You can use the special _remap method in your controller to manually handle the routing - http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#remapping - or you could set up some manual routes in config/routes.php

Answer (score 0):

write a new function and define custom routes for it in routes.php if you want to achieve it.